# Objective-C: writing values to a specific index of an Array inside a  .plist

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsarray, nsdictionary, writetofile

I understand I can for instance write a value to a .plist file as such

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"stored" ofType:@"plist"];
NSString *comment = @"this is a comment"; 
[comment writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

But If i had for say an Array inside my .plist (gameArray) and I'd like to white `comment` into a particular index of my array i.e. `gameArray[4]` ; how would I do this ?

allow me to clarify

- I have a plist: `stored.plist`
- inside my plist there is an array `gameArray`
- i would like to update specific indexes of `gameArray` inside the plist 
  is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the contents of 'stored.plist' is an array, you need to instantiate a mutable array from the path:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"stored" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSString *comment = @"this is a comment"; 

// inserting a new object:
[array insertObject:comment atIndex:4];

// replacing an existing object:
// classic obj-c syntax
[array replaceObjectAtIndex:4 withObject:4];        
// obj-c literal syntax:
array[4] = comment;

// Cannot save to plist inside your document bundle.
// Save a copy inside ~/Library/Application Support

NSURL *documentsURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] objectAtIndex:0];
NSURL *arrayURL = [documentsURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[filePath lastPathComponent]];
[array writeToURL:arrayURL atomically:NO];
```

Comment: yes but now u just have a data type `array` with the `comment` at index 4, this does not write to the .plist, i want to write to the actual .plist

Comment: Added sample code to save to  ~/Library/Application Support/stored.plist

Comment: yes but this adds an array to the .plist, it doesn't update the existing one: is it not possible too update the existing one ?

Comment: On first run, you could copy the default plist from your document bundle to ~/Library/Application Support, then update & save to that location.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update and save data in application's main bundle instead you have to do in document directory or other directory like this:

```
 NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *plistFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"stored.plist"];

if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPAth:plistFilePath]) 
{//already exits

   NSMutableArray *data = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistFilePath];
   //update your array here
   NSString *comment = @"this is a comment";
   [data replaceObjectAtIndex:4 withObject:comment];

   //write file here
   [data writeToFile:plistFilePath atomically:YES];
}
else{ //firstly take content from plist and then write file document directory 

 NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"stored" ofType:@"plist"];
 NSMutableArray *data = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
 //update your array here
   NSString *comment = @"this is a comment";
   [data replaceObjectAtIndex:4 withObject:comment];

   //write file here
   [data writeToFile:plistFilePath atomically:YES];
}
```

Comment: thank you for this, but what your code is doing is adding an array `data` into my plist, I have an array in it already, which I'm trying to update  . . . .

Comment: Firstly find your root structure say its array or dictinary like this: NSMutableArray *data = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath]; or NSMutableDictionary *data = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

Comment: your structure will be dictionary with arrays